# In Oracle Enterprise 19c, is there a way of finding what procedure is executing a commit?

Tags: oracle-19c

I have a loop in a procedure which calls a number of other procedures. At the end of the loop, it does a commit. However, based on the results I am seeing it appears it is doing a commit on each iteration in the loop.

I have manually searched the code and cannot find the commit. Is there any table or view which will tell me the procedure which contained the last commit executed?

Comment: No, there isn't such a table or view.

Comment: A down vote for asking a well formed question? Someone needs their coffee.

Comment: Its common, people seem to downvote if they  dont like the question or if they dont like you.  I will balance it .

Comment: I'm curious, how do you suppose someone drinking coffee might improve the quality of your question?

Comment: Some folks just aren't ready to work & play well with others until they have had that first cup of coffee, tea, other substance or ritual. I believe the question I asked which may have the simple answer you provided, is still valid. Perhaps it might spark an idea in a developer's brain.

Comment: @mustaccio If you have a suggestion as to how to ask the question better, or a method to achieve the desired results, which is to find a commit hidden in a multilevel call stack, I would love to hear it.

Comment: @PaulStearns [disable commit in procedure](https://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2014/05/disable-commit-in-procedure.html)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov that looks interesting. I didn’t know this.

Comment: Maybe sql-tracing, pl/sql-tracing or pl/sql-debug may help you to locate the commit. But these need appropriate privileges and maybe some of them shouldn’t be done on a production system.

Answer (score 0):

, you can use the V$TRANSACTION view to obtain information about the current active transactions. Specifically, you can check the XIDUSN, XIDSLOT, and XIDSQN columns from the view to identify the transaction associated with a specific commit.

Here's how you can check which procedure contains the last commit executed:

SELECT s.sid, s.serial#, s.username, t.start_time, t.used_ublk, t.used_urec, t.status
FROM v$session s
JOIN v$transaction t ON s.saddr = t.ses_addr
WHERE s.username = '<YOUR_USERNAME>';

Replace <YOUR_USERNAME> with the appropriate username of the session that is executing the procedure.

Note down the SID and SERIAL# of the session that is performing the commits.

Next, find the SQL statements associated with that session (including commits):

Look for the SQL_TEXT that includes the COMMIT statement. The SQL_ID and PREV_SQL_ID columns will help you track the sequence of executed SQL statements.

Comment: In running "select * from v$transaction;" I get no rows.

Comment: I don’t think that this will work. You will not see the transaction in the v$transaction table after it is committed. But there are other ways to identify the session. So let’s assume the OP already knows the session data. But I think there is no way to find out the pl/sql code he executed. There is no SQL-code that contains the COMMIT. Please try out your proposal and report us your results.